# "the Stack Exchange"

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, documentation

The [API docs on throttles](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) has the following paragraph at the end of the page:

> While not strictly a throttle, the Stack Exchange employs heavy caching and as such no application should make semantically identical requests more than once a minute. This is generally a waste of bandwidth, as more often than not the exact same result will be returned.

Stack Exchange has been stripped of it's personhood and assigned the definite article :-(. I think this should read as follows. I've added "API" <sub>and fiddled with the commas in the last sentence.</sub>

> While not strictly a throttle, the Stack Exchange API employs heavy caching and as such no application should make semantically identical requests more than once a minute. This is generally a waste of bandwidth as, more often than not, the exact same result will be returned.

Comment: I guess the Kevin Montrose is to blame.

Comment: Well, I think its personhood should be restored and then be Knighted:  "While not strictly a throttle, Sir Stack Exchange welds a heavy caching mechanism ..."  This would quell any concerns that the API is not robust enough. ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've changed the text to read as follows:

> While not strictly a throttle, the Stack Exchange API employs heavy caching and as such no application should make semantically identical requests more than once a minute. This is generally a waste of bandwidth as, more often than not, the exact same result will be returned.

This will be live in the next API production build, which will happen "soon."